# on.click only works once despite it turns off

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been trying to make this code works each time a user click on option from a select value. The problem is that it only works once. The next time a user click on other option it does not work. I have tried to stop propagation, turn it off and simply does not work.

What am I missing? I need to extract information from the id of the option value.

**Here it is:**

```
$(document).on('click', '.opdate', function() {


  var num_dates = "<?php echo "
  $num_dates_2 ";?>";

  var text = $(this).attr("id").replace("op", "");

  var result = text.split('*');

  var position = result[0];
  var num_row = result[1];

  if (num_dates != position) {
    $('#concatenate_div_final').attr({
      style: ""
    });
    $('#concatenate_final').attr({
      id: "concatenate_final" + num_row
    });
  }

  if (num_dates == position) {
    $('#concatenate_div_final').attr({
      style: "display:none"
    });


  }

});
```

Comment: It is unclear how this code behaves currently. Please post relevant HTML as well.

Comment: *"click on option"* sounds very suspicious since events are not supported on `<option>` in some browsers. Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Please post your html code to which you are referring to.

Comment: I think your problem is "num_dates" var. It takes value from a php veritable. Although plz post your html code for more clear understanding.

Comment: Note that when you change the `id` of `$('#concatenate_final')` you can no longer target that element with the original id as selector. Also provide a proper explanation of what you are trying to accomplish with this code as per [ask]